# How can add an underline using ruby on rails and css?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working with ruby on rails and I"m not very familiar with the language. What I want to do is fairly straight forward. I have a language toggle bar which allows the user to choose the language with which they can view the site.

I want to underline the selected language when it is chosen. But I'm not sure how to add a class or a span so that I can just underline (bottom-border) one of the languages.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="language">
        <% if @language == :fr %>
            <%= link_to 'English', language_path(language: :en)  %>
            <span>|</span>
          French
      <% else %>
        English |
        <%= link_to 'French', language_path(language: :fr)  %>
      <% end %>
</div>
```

Can someone please help me? When I select the class 'Language' it underlines both the "English|French" entirely, when all I really want is to underline the language that is currently selected. So either or, not both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the active language into its own span and style it there

```
<div class="language">
    <% if @language == :fr %>
      <%= link_to 'English', language_path(language: :en)  %>
      <span>|</span>
      <span class="selected">French</span>
    <% else %>
      <span class="selected">English</span>
      <span>|</span>
      <%= link_to 'French', language_path(language: :fr)  %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.language > .selected {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

You might also need to style your generated anchor tags to have `text-decoration: none;`, since they are probably underlined by default (as is good practice anyhow). In any case, don't use `border-bottom` for this.

**Having said all that, I think you need to make it as clear as possible that the currently unselected language *is* an anchor tag. When people see underline, they tend to assume the underlined thing is a link. Conversely, things with no underline that ARE links constitute surprising behavior.**